# Laravel error interface class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, interface, namespaces, repository

I am very new to "Advanced Laravel" so to speak, however I do know most of the basics and I am trying to understand what namespacing, interfaces and repositories is all about, since I came across it not so long ago.

However, I am getting the following error, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong:

Class app\models\Interfaces\CategoriesInterface does not exist

Below is my code:

Routes.php

```
App::bind('App\Models\Interfaces\BaseInterface',  'App\Models\Repositories\BaseRepository');
```

CategoriesController.php

```
<?php
use app\models\Interfaces\CategoriesInterface;

class CategoriesController extends BaseController
{
protected $categories;

public function __construct(CategoriesInterface $categories)
{
    $this->categories = $categories;
}
```

BaseInterface.php

```
<?php

interface BaseInterface
{
public function all();
}
```

CategoriesInterface.php

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Interfaces;
interface CategoriesInterface extends BaseInterface { }
```

CategoriesRepository.php

```
<?php namespace app\models\Repositories;
use App\Models\Interfaces\CategoriesInterface;
use Categories;

class CategoriesRepository implements CategoriesInterface
{
public function all()
{
    $categories = $this->categories->all();
    return $categories;
}
}
```

EloquentCategoriesRepository.php

```
<?php namespace app\models\Repositories;
use App\Models\Interfaces\CategoriesInterface;
class EloquentCategoriesRepository implements CategoriesInterface {

public function all()
{
    return Categories::all();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try name spacing the classes/interfaces properly. `EloquentCategoriesRepository.php` and `CategoriesRepository` are having `app` instead of `App` in the namespace. And `CategoriesController` too needs to use `App\..` not `app\..`.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to implement the repository pattern, which at first it might seem a bit 'advanced' but it's actually pretty simple.

So the basic idea is to abstract the data layer of your application with the database to make your transitions from one DBS to another(ex. Mysql to Mongo).

In other words your are trying to make the business logic of your application independent to the data layer (Where you query your collections/instances), so when you reach a point that you might want to change your database you can just implement another repository. The Interfaces are there to provide a contract between your application and the data layer.

Laravel implementation of the repository pattern it's pretty straight forward.

- Create your interface
- Create your interface's repository (actual implementation)
- Bind the repository using a service provider class (Or in your case `App::bind`)
- Instantiate the dependency in to your controller using the repository

Don't forget to auto load your namespaces using `psr-04`.

In your case I think the problem is you are not autoloading the namespace.

Also `CategoriesRepository.php` & `EloquentCategoriesRepository.php` are both Eloquent repositories and will return Eloquent collections. To return an array of `stdClass` (standar PDO) you will have to use the `\DB` facade.

If my answer does not cover you please take a look [here](http://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/)

Comment: What do you mean not autoloading the namespace?